# JavascriptObject to string gwt

Tags: javascript, gwt, javascript-objects

I have become a great fan of the JavaScriptOverlayTypes.

so lets say, I have the followin JSON object:

```
 {
  "product": {
    "name": "Widget",
    "prices": 
      { "minQty": 1, "price": 12.49 }
  }
}
```

So I write my class for products and one for prices. Now if somethings wents wrong when analysing the "price JavascriptObject", I want to print it as the following:

```
{ "minQty": 1, "price": 12.49 }
```

but I havent found a possibilty yet to confert the "price JavascriptObject" backt to a string.

Is there a possibilty to do this?

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new JSONObject(priceJso).toString()`

Beware of performance thugh, as it'll create a JSONValue object for each property of the object (and recursively of course), and I'm not sure the GWT compiler is able to optimize things much.
In your case, as an "error path", it should be OK though.

Comment: cool, exactly what I wanted. Note, that you have to include <inherits name="com.google.gwt.json.JSON" /> into your projects *.gwt.xml file.

On other note, is there a possibility to print the JSON file in a nicely formatted manner?

Comment: your module (`.gwt.xml`) has to inherit the JSON module to make it work: `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.json.JSON" />`

Answer (score 1):

[JsonUtils](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html#stringify(com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject)) has a nice function for it:

```
String jsonString = JsonUtils.stringify(priceJson);
```

Which has the native implementation:

```
public static native String stringify(JavaScriptObject obj) /*-{ JSON.stringify(obj); }-*/;
```